# non-type template argument is not a constant expression Number<num, num, int>

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have the following problem in my code. I´m trying to create a variable num, ask to the user with a std::cin and then pass it to my template. But it says
"non-type template argument is not a constant expression" pointing my variable num in the template.
I´ve tried to use "int num", "const int num" and "const static int num", and no one works. Any idea?

What i have tried:

```
    int num; // no
    static int num; // one 
    const static int num = 0; // works
    std::cin >> num;
    Number<num, num, int> N1(10); // here
    Number<16, 3, int> N2(10);
    std::cout << N1 + N2;
```

Main code :

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <iostream>

 #include <cerrno>
 #include <exception>

 #include "number.hpp"



 int main()
 {
     try
     {
         int num; // Here..

         std::cin >> num;

         Number<num, num, int> N1(10); // Here..
         Number<16, 3, int> N2(10);

         std::cout << N1 + N2;

         N1.suma(N2).write(std::cout);

         std::cout << N1 * N2;

     }
     catch (const std::system_error &e)
     {
         std::cerr << e.what() << '\n';
     }
 }
```

And here is the class:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

#include <exception>
#include <cerrno> 

template <size_t B, size_t N, typename T = char> // here is the template
class Number
{

private:
  T main_number = NULL;
  void toBase(int valor);

public:
  std::vector<T> v; // Vector que contendrá el numero desglozado

   Number(int valor); // Constructor
  ~Number();

  Number<B, N, T> operator+(const Number<B, N, T> &operando);
  Number<B, N, T> operator-(const Number<B, N, T> &operando);
  Number<B, N, T> operator*(const Number<B, N, T> &operando);

  Number<B, N, T> suma(const Number<B, N, T> &sumando) const;
  Number<B, N, T> resta(const Number<B, N, T> &sumando) const;
  Number<B, N, T> producto(const Number<B, N, T> &sumando) const;

  std::ostream &write(std::ostream &os) const;
  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, Number<B, N, T> &);
};
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's just not possible. Templates are compile-time constructs and a value gotten from `cin` is a run-time value. For e template to work, the template parameters need to be known at compile time.

Comment: So its impossible to ask for a number and make a template dynamic?

Comment: @Michalistico it is.

Comment: A template is basically a "mold" that generates different versions of code during compilation. Once the program is compiled and running there is no template. There is only different instantiations of that template (different versions).

Comment: That´s bad.. Thank you guys!